# Git: Adding a file to a remote directory keeps failing

Tags: git

So I'm trying to use Github for the first time. I'm working on a repository that was created for me by the project leader.

I went to my desired directory

```
/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/my_issues
```

I created the directory.

```
Abrahams-MBP:abiomed_issues abrahammathew$ git clone https://github.com/ml_projects/my_repo.git
    ...
    Checking connectivity... done.
```

Initializing was done

```
Abrahams-MBP:my_issues abrahammathew$ git init
```

Added the files to my local repository

```
Abrahams-MBP:my_issues abrahammathew$ git add my_data_extraction.py
```

Commited for the first time

```
Abrahams-MBP:my_issues abrahammathew$ git commit -m "first commit"
```

Remotely added the origin.

```
Abrahams-MBP:abiomed_issues abrahammathew$ git remote add origin https://github.com/abmathewks/my_repo.git
```

Finally, I tried to push the file to github.

```
Abrahams-MBP:my_issues abrahammathew$ git push -u origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/abmathewks/my_repo.git/' not found
```

So the final step isn't working. Can anyone help diagnose this issue. I've specified the right repo, so I'm not sure why it's not found. Here's my local directory and it's contents.

```
Abrahams-MBP:my_issues abrahammathew$ ls -a
.               my_data_extraction.py
..              my_explore.py
.DS_Store       my_repo
.git
```

Also tried this:

```
Abrahams-MBP:my_issues abrahammathew$ git push -u origin:master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname origin: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And a generic push

```
Abrahams-MBP:my_issues abrahammathew$ git push 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/abmathewks/my_repo.git/' not found
```

Comment: shouldnt that be `origin:master` ? You aready added the remote - why do you need to specify it explicit?

Comment: It's not at all normal to run `git clone` and then `git init`. The normal sequence is `git clone` followed by `cd` into the clone-created repository. Note that `git clone` does `mkdir` + `cd` + `git init` + `git remote add` + `git fetch` + `git checkout`, all as one big composite operation. The sub-commands run in the new Git directory, but when they are done, you're still not yet in the new Git directory.

Comment: 1. You are doing several unnecessary commands. 2. You have only created a local copy of the repo. You did not create a remote repo on GitHub under your account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are doing several unnecessary steps. It is possible that some of these are conflicting with each other.

To create an empty repo from scratch, you use

```
$ git init
```

To connect this new repo to an existing one, then you can do

```
$ git remote add <name> <URL>
```

On the other hand, you do not need to do either of these two steps when you clone a repo with

```
$ git clone <URL>
```

This automatically initializes the directory for use with git and sets up a remote named `origin` which refers to the given URL. If you want to add other remotes, then you can use `git remote add` with a name other than `origin`.

If you want to copy an existing repo from GitHub, you have two options:

1. [Fork the GitHub repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) to create your own personal copy. Then `git clone` that copy to your local machine to work with. Use the URL for your fork.
2. `git clone` the original GitHub repo with the URL from the original repo. Then [create a new personal repo](https://github.com/new). You can either change the remote URL for `origin`:

   ```
   $ git remote set-url origin <URL>
   ```

   or add a new remote to point to your new blank repo:

   ```
   $ git remote add my-personal-repo <URL>
   ```

After creating the repository correctly, do these commands as needed:

```
$ git add <file name>
$ git commit -m 'Some message'
$ git push
```